# How to make a notification vibrate and sound once, and then ideally be muted afterward?

Tags: root-access, notifications, audio, notification-bar, vibration

What I am looking to do is, get a notification as normal with vibration and sound, and then any further notifications from that app I want to not vibrate. For context, it would be the most helpful for a messaging app, where I would like to be informed when I receive a message, but I don't want my phone vibrating over and over if they are to send more than one message before I can reply. Just once is enough to let me know I have a message, I don't need 27 vibrations in my pocket. This sort of dynamic reaction to a notification would be extremely helpful for me, with the notification acting normally at first, and then if it is already present in the notification "bar" or "tab" (Im not sure what its called exactly), then it wouldn't do something like vibrate or sound my phone. I am not sure if any apps can control notifications like this, so I am here to ask for help. I am willing to root my phone if I need in order to get this functionality, so lets me know about any method you got, Thanks!

Additionally if anyone can think of a good method of receiving the notification you can let me know, I might not need my phone to vibrate or sound at all if there is a good alternative, but those are the only ways that I can think to inform me hands-free and from my pocket, and something like my phone notification led, while less intrusive, wouldn't really work.